# Should I use HTTP 302 instead of HTTP 301 in this case?

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have a website example.com

People come to my site to calculate some stuff and get their results like

example.com/result/oiwajefoijh238fjiow
example.com/result/jifomoiemowajefji33

They would spread the links on social networks like Twitter and Facebook.

But I don't want people from those links stay with the suffix. Is it good to do 301 or 302 from `example.com/result/oiwajefoijh238fjiow` to `example.com`?

I add those suffix for saving some status and it will be recognized by other servers (rather than browsers)

Answer (score 0):

**3××** is mainly used for **REDIRECTION.**

**301** mean **MOVED PERMANENTLY**
The target resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs.

**302** means **FOUND**
The target resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client ought to continue to use the effective request URI for future requests.

You can read more here at [HTTPSTATUSES](https://httpstatuses.com/)